# "First defined here" - omnetpp

Tags: c++, omnet++

Im new im ***omnet++*** and don't have much experience in **c++**. I trying to create my first simulation similary to project that I found on tutorial, but I get this error:

```
first defined here
```

almost next to every method in **Message.cpp** (except 
`Message::Message(const char *name, int kind) : cPacket(name,kind), getMessageID() and setMessageID()`).

**Other posts didn't solve my problem.*

**Message.h:**

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_MESSAGE_H_
#define MESSAGE_MESSAGE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

class Message: public ::cPacket{
    protected:
        int src_var;
        int dst_var;
        int sessionID_var;
        int messageID_var;
        int priority_var;
        double creationTime_var;

      private:
        void copy(const Message& other);

      protected:
        // protected and unimplemented operator==(), to prevent accidental usage
        bool operator==(const Message&);

      public:
        Message(const char *name=NULL, int kind=0);
        Message(const Message& other);
        virtual ~Message();
        Message& operator=(const Message& other);

        virtual int getSrc() const;
        virtual void setSrc(int src);
        virtual int getDst() const;
        virtual void setDst(int dst);
        virtual int getSessionID() const;
        virtual void setSessionID(int sessionID);
        virtual int getMessageID() const;
        virtual void setMessageID(int messageID);
        virtual int getPriority() const;
        virtual void setPriority(int priority);
        virtual double getCreationTime() const;
        virtual void setCreationTime(double creationTime);
};

#endif /* MESSAGE_MESSAGE_H_ */
```

**Message.cpp:**

```
#include "Message.h"

Message::Message(const char *name, int kind) : cPacket(name,kind)
{
    this->src_var = 0;
    this->dst_var = 0;
    this->sessionID_var = 0;
    this->messageID_var = 0;
    this->priority_var = 0;
    this->creationTime_var = 0;
}

Message::Message(const Message& other) : cPacket(other)
{
    copy(other);
}

Message::~Message()
{
}

void Message::copy(const Message& other)
{
    this->src_var = other.src_var;
    this->dst_var = other.dst_var;
    this->sessionID_var = other.sessionID_var;
    this->messageID_var = other.messageID_var;
    this->priority_var = other.priority_var;
    this->creationTime_var = other.creationTime_var;
}

int Message::getSrc() const
{
    return src_var;
}

void Message::setSrc(int src)
{
    this->src_var = src;
}

int Message::getDst() const
{
    return dst_var;
}

void Message::setDst(int dst)
{
    this->dst_var = dst;
}

int Message::getSessionID() const
{
    return sessionID_var;
}

void Message::setSessionID(int sessionID)
{
    this->sessionID_var = sessionID;
}

int Message::getMessageID() const
{
    return messageID_var;
}

void Message::setMessageID(int messageID)
{
    this->messageID_var = messageID;
}

int Message::getPriority() const
{
    return priority_var;
}

void Message::setPriority(int priority)
{
    this->priority_var = priority;
}

double Message::getCreationTime() const
{
    return creationTime_var;
}

void Message::setCreationTime(double creationTime)
{
    this->creationTime_var = creationTime;
}
```

**EDIT: 2**

Console output:

```
15:15:58 **** Build of configuration debug for project TIRT ****
make MODE=debug all 
MSGC: message/Message.msg
generator/BasicGenerator.cpp
generator/PoissonGenerator.cpp
message/Message.cpp
message/Message_m.cpp
Creating executable: out/gcc-debug//TIRT.exe
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::Message(Message const&)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:192: multiple definition of `Message::Message(Message const&)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:20: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::Message(Message const&)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:192: multiple definition of `Message::Message(Message const&)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:20: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::~Message()':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:197: multiple definition of `Message::~Message()'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:25: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::~Message()':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:197: multiple definition of `Message::~Message()'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:25: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::~Message()':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:197: multiple definition of `Message::~Message()'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:25: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::copy(Message const&)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:210: multiple definition of `Message::copy(Message const&)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:30: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::getSrc() const':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:242: multiple definition of `Message::getSrc() const'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:40: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::setSrc(int)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:247: multiple definition of `Message::setSrc(int)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:45: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::getDst() const':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:252: multiple definition of `Message::getDst() const'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:50: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::setDst(int)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:257: multiple definition of `Message::setDst(int)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:55: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::getSessionID() const':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:262: multiple definition of `Message::getSessionID() const'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:60: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::setSessionID(int)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:267: multiple definition of `Message::setSessionID(int)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:65: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::getMessageID() const':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:272: multiple definition of `Message::getMessageID() const'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:70: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::setMessageID(int)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:277: multiple definition of `Message::setMessageID(int)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:75: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::getPriority() const':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:282: multiple definition of `Message::getPriority() const'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:80: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::setPriority(int)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:287: multiple definition of `Message::setPriority(int)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:85: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::getCreationTime() const':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:292: multiple definition of `Message::getCreationTime() const'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:90: first defined here
out/gcc-debug//message/Message_m.o: In function `Message::setCreationTime(double)':
D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message_m.cpp:297: multiple definition of `Message::setCreationTime(double)'
out/gcc-debug//message/Message.o:D:\omnetpp-5.1.1\samples\TIRT/message/Message.cpp:95: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:89: out/gcc-debug//TIRT.exe] Error 1

15:16:05 Build Finished (took 7s.819ms)
```

**EDIT 3. SOLVED:**

There was a problem, because I manually created `Message` class (`Message.cpp` and `Message.h`) plus `Message.msg` as "template" so compiler had problem with this(multiple definition). This is what happen when you sit too long.

Comment: Post the exact error message verbatim. Also your linker command line please.

Comment: Screen with errors added

Comment: Did you create `message.msg` file? Do you have files both files: `Message.cpp` and `Message_m.cpp`?

Comment: Click over to console and look at the error full output. The mutilated version shown in the problem tab is useless far too often. If the longer error message still doesn't help you solve the problem, paste in the contents of the console and remove the image.

Comment: @JerzyD. yeah I created `Message.msg`, now I see it generated automatically `Message_m.cpp` from this file, thats why I had error because it occurs twice, compiled from `Message.cpp`and from `Message.msg`. Thanks